# Constructing a CGAL point with a vector

Tags: c++, cgal

I am interested in taking advantage of the **CGAL** `Min_sphere_of_spheres_d` class.
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__sphere__of__spheres__d.html

I am able to run their example program, but it does not do quite what I want.

In particular the dimension of their example is fixed to `3`. I would like to give the user the option to choose the dimension of the point meaning a variable dimension.

This however appears to be a problem since the Point class appears to require a fixed size array of coordinates as input :

```
FT coord[D];
Point p(D,coord,coord+D);
```

Is it possible to instead pass a `vector` to the `point` `constructor`? If so how?

Comment: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/2480

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to CGAL and don't use C++ very often so I thought that I was being silly. Good to know that I'm not, frustrating that they don't offer that functionality.